# Setting boundaries for matrix-gesture-detector

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector) package for pinch-zoom and scrolling across a widget, in this case I'm using a GridView.count.

I want to make it so there are boundaries on each side of the widget, so the user may not scroll or zoom out-of-bounds.

I managed to make it work so it doesn't zoom out of bounds, and limited the scroll in the left, and the top side.
However, I'm having trouble limiting the right and bottom bounds.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TransformDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class TransformDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transform Demo'),
      ),
      body: MatrixGestureDetector(
        onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
          double x = 0;
          double y = 0;
          if (m.getTranslation()[0] < 0) {
            x = m.getTranslation()[0];
          } 
          if (m.getTranslation()[1] < 0) {
            y = m.getTranslation()[1];
          }
          m.setTranslationRaw(x, y, 0);
          if (m.determinant() > 0.99) {
            notifier.value = m;
          } else {
            m.setIdentity();
            notifier.value.setIdentity();
          }
        },
        shouldRotate: false,
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: notifier,
          builder: (ctx, child) {
            return Transform(
              transform: notifier.value,
              child: new Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[...getRows()],
                  )),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getRows() {
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      list.add(new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[...getRow(i)],
      ));
    }
    return list;
  }

  getRow(int i) {
    List<Widget> list = new List<Widget>();
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      list.add(Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: new Text(i.toString() + "," + j.toString())));
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

I had trouble because the amount of translation on the X and Y axis depends on the amount of zoom, what can I do to make this work?

Thank you!